# NodeJs Pass variable from httpRequest using Request library to another function

Tags: node.js, function, asynchronous, parameter-passing

Hello, I searched stackoverflow and am having a difficult time finding an answer  to my issue. (I probably am not experienced eneough to know how to ask the question correctly) My issue is that I would like to pass an object called "values" into a function after I make an httpRequest using the npm package "request".

I am new to stackoverflow, so I apologize if this question is redundant. The following code is just a snippet, so if more information is needed, I can provide it.

```
      values = {};
      values.id = req.body.generateID;
      values.type = req.body.deviceType;
      values.parentID = null;
      values.name = req.body.name;
      values.data_collector = "True";
      values.COM = req.body.comType;
      values.ip_address = req.body.ip.split(":")[0]
      values.port = req.body.ip.split(":")[1]

      const uId           = req.body.uId;
      const sesKey        = req.body.sesKey;
      var auth = new Buffer(uId+':'+sesKey);
      const url = "http://"+req.body.ip_address+"/GetModuleInfo.json";
      const headers = {
          "Authorization": auth.toString('base64')
      };

      httpRequest.get({url: url,headers: headers}, callback().bind({values:values}));

      function callback(err, httpResponse, body) {
          if (err) { return res.status(500).end('Error');}
          console.log("checking this",this)
          return body;
      }
```

Comment: what value you want to pass in your values object ?

Comment: the callback will take the values object and use values.id when entering into a database

Comment: I figured it out. I placed the .bind function in the wrong place